# Mesa 9.2 does not support OpenGL 3

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to install OpenGL 3.0 for studying examples about [GLUS](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLUS/) , which require OpenGL 3 or 4.

I read on [the official Mesa website](http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/9.2.html) that Mesa 9.2 support OpenGL 3.0, but after I installed Mesa 9.0, it only support OpenGL 1.4. This is the information  from the command line "glxinfo | grep "OpenGL" ":

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 9.1.4)
OpenGL extensions:
```

My question is how can I get OpenGL 3.0 in Mesa 9.2. I hope to see your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Different hardware drivers support different levels of OpenGL.  The GM45 is an old chip that receives minimal support from developers.  Newer chips, such as those embedded in the Sandy Bridge or Ivy Bridge, generally support the very latest features of Mesa.

You could try using the software rasterizer (llvmpipe being the "high-speed" software rasterizer in Mesa) instead of the hardware drivers.  There is an [llvmpipe installation/usage guide](http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html) available, which admittedly is not all that great.  The gist is that an alternative libGL.so/OpenGL32.dll will be created which you need to put in the right place so the dynamic linker will find it.

If you're on Linux, there may be a package you need to install to get llvmpipe.  Depends on which distro specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. By the way, I would like to ask you whether or not I can use GLUS with llvmpipe?

Comment: No idea.  I've never heard of GLUS before you mentioned it.  The frontpage only lists Windows as its desktop OS, but I see no reason it shouldn't work with Mesa on Windows.  If not, try SDL or GLFW.